# Fantasy story where a young girl (I think) discovers magic, but must then hide from all magicians

Tags: story-identification, novel, books

I remember reading this story many years ago (at least ten).

A young girl (at least I think so), discovers that she has magic by throwing something. However, magic is restricted (or maybe even forbidden) and she must now hide from all magicians in her city. I think the local Thieves Guild helps her, hoping to get their own pet magician.

Other recollections:

- It's low-fantasy, no elves or dragons
- I think there was a lot of homophobia in the setting
- I seem to recall that she can't control her magic and is eventually caught/taken in by the magicians.
- I'm pretty sure it was a full-length novel. Possibly a novella.

Comment: FWIW you don't need the books tag now either... unless you think this might have been part of a series.

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? The answer is the same, but the recollections (and thus the question) are wildly different.

Comment: @GunnarSödergren Yes, we close story id questions as duplicates if the answer is the same. It mainly helps to keep things organised and means that many routes point towards the same answer. Which is, after all, what duplicate closures are meant for.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Ah, gotcha! That makes sense!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Black Magician trilogy, by Trudy Canavan ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Magician))

In the first novel, The Magician's Guild, Sonea is a commoner who discovers her magic in a protest against the magicians, who are all nobles. She's then on the run until eventually she's brought into the school as a student.

One of the other magicians, Lord Dannyl, has to hide his homosexuality from the conservative school.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you!